# Media player that isolates the background music while watching

Tags: video, music, video-player

I want to watch movies without music backgrounds only vocals.

- OS: Windows 10
- Video Source: Local files (MP4/AVC especially)
- Price: Freeware

Comment: If your videos are in 5.1 surround, all you need is to access your Sound control panel & see if you can turn down all but the Centre channel. This is more likely to be at OS-level than application. If your videos are in stereo or mono, this cannot be done.

Comment: what if I converted the audio to 5.1? can I use Boom 3D for that?

Comment: You can't generate sound or channel separation that doesn't already exist.